# Tableview isnt reloading data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reload

What I am trying is fetching some data from service and trying to display it into table view, everything works fine, but data isn't displayed in the first time.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("PostedQuesIds") != nil{


            arr = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("PostedQuesIds") as? NSArray

        }
        else{

            print("I am getting no IDS !!!")
        }

        if self.arr != nil{

            for quesIds in self.arr!{

                print("ids '\(quesIds)'")

                var url = "http://some.com/forum"
                url.appendContentsOf(quesIds as! String)
                WebHandler.sharedInstance.GET_REQ(url)

                self.dataArray = WebHandler.sharedInstance.questionDetails?.objectForKey(quesIds) as? NSMutableArray


            }
        }
```

I TRIED

```
//NO LUCK WITH THE FOLLWING CODE, IT IS RUNNING AS EXPECTED BUT DATA IS NOT //SHOWN
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
//            
//            
//        
//            print("I am called wtf?")
//            self.tableView.reloadData()
//            
//        })
```

Then I thought of doing it through NSNotification; what I did:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "reload", name: "reloadTable", object: nil)
}

func reload(){
//tried in main queue and out
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        print("I am called wtf?")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}
```

Now I don't know what is wrong in it FYI I am posting nsnotification from webhandler class each time and it is working as in my logs I am getting the message. Please help me in this any of your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: does `dataArray ` actually contain any data into it ?

Comment: Can you show code how you are assigning data in UITableViewDataSource methods?

Comment: Yup it contains i have complete log of it @Lamar

Comment: it is perfect as when i visit the same screen second time it shows me complete fetched data from server @SaqibOmer

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible problems:

1. Your `WebHandler.sharedInstance.GET_REQ()` method may be asynchronous. If my guess is correct, `self.tableView.reloadData()` is being called before your web service finishes getting your data and assignes it to `self.dataArray`. You might want to wait for it to finish before calling `reloadData()`.
2. Not sure why you have the following line inside a `for` loop:

   ```
   self.dataArray = WebHandler.sharedInstance.questionDetails?.objectForKey(quesIds) as? NSMutableArray
   ```

   Are you sure you don't want to append to `dataArray`?

Comment: How can i wait if it is aysnc ? and the reason for it being in loop that i have to get the data of all id's present in my array.

Comment: You can add a callback that gets executed after your web service finishes.